# Does executing a python script load it into memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running a python script using `python3 myscript.py` on Ubuntu 16.04. Is the script loaded into memory or read and interpreted line by line from the hdd? If it's not loaded all at once, is there any way of knowing or controlling how big the chunks are, that are loaded into Memory?

Comment: Could you please add to the question what problem you are trying to solve by trying to control how much script is read? Is it out of fear of running out of memory for just reading the script?

Comment: All your code has to be loaded into memory, that seems fairly obvious. From what I've seen, you cannot call functions from the top-level from above where they've been defined, so it seems to load things line by line.

Comment: @musically_ut I was just wondering how the interpreter does it. It's not out of fear of running out of memory, more like curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is loaded into memory in its entirety.  This must be the case, because a syntax error near the end will abort the program straight away.  Try it and see.

There does not need to be any way to control or configure this.  It is surely an implementation detail best left alone.  If you have a problem related to this (e.g. your script is larger than your RAM), it can be solved some other way.

Answer (score 1):

The "script" you use is only the human friendly representation you see. Python opens that script, reads lines, tokenizes them, creates a parse and ast tree for it and then emits bytecode which you can see using the `dis` module.

The "script" isn't loaded, it's code object (the object that contains the instructions generated for it) is. There's no direct way to affect that process. I have never heard of a script being so big that you need to read it in chunks, I'd be surprised if you accomplished it.